# arrays of pointers explain

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

```
char *c[]={"dog","cat","mice","lion","tiger"};
int nr;
int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {for(int j=0;*(*(c+i)+j)!='\0';j++)
            {cout<<*(*(c+i)+j)<<" ";
            if(*(*(c+i)+j)=='i')
                nr++;}
        cout<<"\n";}
    cout<<"\n"<<nr;
}
```

In the second `for`, I do not undesrtand very well the `*(*(c+i)+j)`.I know that my `char` vector contains pointers. `*(c+i)` increments the address of the first element and arrive at element `c+i`.Then what happens? It transform that address into another pointer and increments with `j` and the new address is transformed again into another pointer?
I posted this 'ugly code' only to see how it works because i think that a program is faster if i use pointers to move in an array than index and i dont like to let the compiler do the optimization because i dont like to depend on the machine and to wonder all day if the compiler optimize that or that.

Comment: This is terrible code with terrible indentation. Where did you get it from?

Comment: Sea of sewage - close immediate.

Comment: i wanted to do it like this in order to clarify something at lvl of pointers.Normally i dont write something like this but i wanted to know more deeper what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*(*(c+i)+j)` is equivalent to `c[i][j]`.

It gives you the *j*<sup>th</sup> character of the *i*<sup>th</sup> word.

> It transform that address into another pointer and increments with j and the new address is transformed again into another pointer?

There is no "transformation". `*(c+i)` is a pointer already. A pointer is an object which contains an address.

First `c` is used (implicitly converting it into a pointer), then it is incremented `i` times to get a pointer to the *i*<sup>th</sup> array element.

Then this pointer is dereferenced using `*`, to get the *i*<sup>th</sup> array element itself. That element is a pointer: a pointer to the characters of the *i*<sup>th</sup> word.

Now you increment that pointer `j` times to get a pointer to the *j*<sup>th</sup> character of that word.

Then this pointer is dereferenced using `*`, to get the actual `char`. If it's `'i'`, a counter is incremented.

Remember, you have two (or three) levels of pointers here. That's one of the reasons that this is really awful code. It needs the indentation fixing and it needs all the undocumented pointer arithmetic to be removed.

Comment: this comment i wanted to hear.I now understand what is going on.Thx

Comment: No problem, @OtnielMercea.